# print contents of directory to file with element type

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm reading [this](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10402034-263.html) article, but I don't understand how I can combine `ls -l /users/Thomas/desktop` with `ls > ~/FILE.txt` to save the contents of the desktop to a file on the desktop (or somewhere else). Also, is there a way to save the type of element being listed (file or folder)?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `ls -l /users/Thomas/desktop > ~/FILE.txt` ? (Also, there is a `-p` option showing type indicator -- trailing `/` for folders).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Thank you, but unfortunately that did not make a file for me. Also, using this sytax, would I put the `-p` directly after the `-l`?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put `-p`, but it's common practice to have options together (both `ls -l -p` and `ls -lp` are valid and mean the same thing). And the redirection *did* make a file, it's in your home directory (*not* on your desktop; do `echo "$HOME"` in terminal to know where exactly).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Aha you're right! It definitely did. Very cool. Just off the top of your head, is there anyway to set what field to sort them? Would you like to submit this as an answer, so I can tick it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Combining `ls` arguments with redirection:

```
ls -l /users/Thomas/desktop > ~/FILE.txt
```

`-p` option adds type indicator, showing trailing `/` for directories:

```
ls -lp /users/Thomas/desktop > ~/FILE.txt
```

`~/FILE.txt` is created in your home directory (`echo "$HOME"` is a good way to know where it is).

[Answering an extra question in the comment]: there is a number of short options (one-letter options) controlling sort order: `-t`, `-S`, `-U` and `-X`, having a common long-form equivalent `--sort=time|size|none|extension`. Additionally, `--time=atime|access|use` specifies the *kind* of time to be used for `ls -t`/`ls --sort=time`.